# Unable to Detect Data Location in Google BigQuery via Google Colab

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, google-colaboratory, database-connection

I'm currently trying to access my data stored in Google BigQuery from Google Colab using Python. I have verified that the location of my data is in the US, and I'm authenticating with the correct account, which is the owner of the project. Despite this, I keep receiving a NotFound error indicating that the table was not found in the US location.

Here is the Python code I'm using in Google Colab:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.colab import auth

auth.authenticate_user()
client = bigquery.Client(project='my_project', location='US')

sql = """
    SELECT * FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table`
    LIMIT 10
"""
df = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()
df.head()
```

The error I'm getting is:
NotFound: 404 Not found: Table my_project:my_dataset.my_table was not found in location US.

I have double-checked the project ID, dataset ID, and table ID, and they are all correct. I have also ensured that the Google account I'm using for authentication in Google Colab has the necessary permissions for this BigQuery project.

What could be the reason for this issue and how can I resolve it? Any help would be much appreciated.